# Looking for a function that maps natural numbers (zero included) into the series [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, ...]

Tags: functions

I need a function that maps natural numbers (starting from zero) into the series [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, ...], i.e.:
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 0
f(2) = 2
f(3) = 1
f(4) = 0
f(5) = 2
...

The function f(x) = mod(x, 3) gives the series [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...], but I can't come up with a function to get the series I want.

Comment: Hint: you want something like $f(-x+c)$ as to reverse the order and shift the zero point.

Comment: You want to reverse the order from 012 to 210... so try subtracting.  Next, you want to shift it, so try adding.  Try $(1-x)\% 3$ or similar (*where we have $\%$ defined in the more common math way such that negative arguments still return non-negative results.  note that not all programming languages follow this*)

Comment: Aside from the suggestions in the comments above, there's also nothing wrong with this obvious way to write the function: $$f(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\equiv 0 (mod~3)\\0&n\equiv 1 (mod~ 3)\\2&n\equiv 2 (mod~3)\end{cases}$$

Comment: $$f(n)=1-n-3\left\lfloor\frac{1-n}{3}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: An alternate approach is you use the generating function $$\frac{1+2x^2}{1-x^3}$$ and then use partial fractions to get it in the form: $$f(n)=a+b\omega^n+c\omega^{2n},$$ where $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2.$

Comment: @JMoravitz  Ah I forgot that mod works weird for negative numbers! In Python, (1 - x)%3 does the job perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Thank you, but isn't in the first example, f(0) = 0? Also, in the second example, f(1) = 3/0 = indeterminate, right?

Comment: My first example has $f(0)=1-0+3*\lfloor (1-0)/3\rfloor=1-0+0=1.$ In the generating function, my formula for $f$ doesn’t involve division. (The generating function is *not* $f.$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it one step at a time.

f(x) = mod(x, 3) gives the series [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...]

f(x) = mod(x + 1, 3) shifts that to [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, ...]

f(x) = 2 - mod(x + 1, 3) is a winner [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, ...]

Comment: Thank you, this indeed generates the desired sequence; the simpler function f(x) = mod(1 - x, 3) proposed by @JMoravitz also works, at least in Python.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=1-\frac2{\sqrt3}\sin\frac{2\pi x}3$$